# How do I map my blender enviorment for Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, modeling

I have a little prototype environment I made in Blender. I have it imported in blender and I'm happy with it.

How can I set my colliders to match exactly my model? I have hills and a house on there, Can I use a navmesh?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you can try.

The first option is, you can add a [Mesh Collider](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MeshCollider.html) component on your object with the correct mesh in it.

[image]

A second option is, you can click the mesh itself (asset) and in the inspector, enable the `Generate Colliders` option.

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is correct, that is the same thing i did on a game which used a map from blender. Great way of displaying your answer too :D

Answer (score -1):

you can add a mesh collider and select the custom mesh option and select the matching mesh object.